# Difficultly correcting executing code

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have been trying to pull some XML data from a website and can't seem to get my loop to cycle through each accrualend date, and the last element should be a total rate as opposed to the single day rate. Below is the code, please be gentle as I am just learning VBA and XML as well. Thanks for any help you may give.

```
Sub getXMLFRN()
    Dim xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xnodesls As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim xnode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim strcusip As String
    Dim straccrualStart As String
    Dim straccrualEnd As String
    Dim strdailyAccruedInterestPer100 As String
    Dim strinterestPaymentPeriodAccruedInterestPer100 As String

    Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmldoc.async = False
    xmldoc.Load ("http://www.treasurydirect.gov/TA_WS/FRN/912828D31?format=xml")
    For i = 1 To 10
        Application.Workbooks("xml test.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:e1").Formula = Array("CUSIP", "Accrual Start", "Accrual End", "Daily Rate", "Total Rate")
        strcusip = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("cusip").Item(0).Text
        straccrualStart = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("accrualStart").Item(0).Text
        straccrualEnd = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("accrualEnd").Item(0).Text
        strdailyAccruedInterestPer100 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("dailyAccruedInterestPer100").Item(0).Text
        strinterestPaymentPeriodAccruedInterestPer100 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("interestPaymentPeriodAccruedInterestPer100").Item(0).Text

        Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = strcusip
        Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = straccrualStart
        Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = straccrualEnd
        Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = strdailyAccruedInterestPer100
        Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = interestPaymentPeriodAccruedInterestPer100
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get your code to work (I have had that issue with the DOMDocument60 before) but I could run it if I change to DOMDocument type, instead.

I am surprised this code works, although perhaps the DomDocument60 supports some other functionality. With a DOMDocument, the `.Load` method takes a string (xml), **not** a URL.  When I run your code, I get an error on that line.

In any case, I use an XMLHttp to get the responsetext from that URL, and load *that* response text to the `xmldoc`

The problem is that while you have a loop `For i = 1 to 10`, you're not incrementing the index position of the `getElementsByTagName` method -- every time you execute that method, you're getting `Item(0)`.  Change that to `Item(i-1)`, and this should work (assuming there are at least 10 matching elements (if not, there may be error).

```vb
Sub getXMLFRN()
    Dim xmlRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim xnodesls As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim xnode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim strcusip As String
    Dim straccrualStart As String
    Dim straccrualEnd As String
    Dim strdailyAccruedInterestPer100 As String
    Dim strinterestPaymentPeriodAccruedInterestPer100 As String

    Set xmlRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    xmlRequest.Open "Get", "http://www.treasurydirect.gov/TA_WS/FRN/912828D31?format=xml", False
    xmlRequest.Send

    Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    xmldoc.LoadXML xmlRequest.responseText

    For i = 1 To 10
        Application.Workbooks("xml test.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:e1").Formula = Array("CUSIP", "Accrual Start", "Accrual End", "Daily Rate", "Total Rate")
        strcusip = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("cusip").Item(i-1).Text
        straccrualStart = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("accrualStart").Item(i-1).Text
        straccrualEnd = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("accrualEnd").Item(i-1).Text
        strdailyAccruedInterestPer100 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("dailyAccruedInterestPer100").Item(i-1).Text
        strinterestPaymentPeriodAccruedInterestPer100 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("interestPaymentPeriodAccruedInterestPer100").Item(i-1).Text

        Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = strcusip
        Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = straccrualStart
        Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = straccrualEnd
        Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = strdailyAccruedInterestPer100
        Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = interestPaymentPeriodAccruedInterestPer100
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

**Update**

To deal with an unknown/varying number of items, use a loop structure that instead of using hardcoded "10" or "100", etc., uses the appropriate last-index of the document.  This of course assumes that there are the same number of each tag name ("cusip", "accrualstart", etc.) and that they are all "related" (i.e., "cusip".Item(0) is related to all of the other `.Item(0)`'s, which appears to be true).

```vb
For i = 1 To xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("cusip").length
   '''
   '''
   '''
Next i
```

Comment: Oops it should be `item(i-1)` I'm on mobile right now and can'tedit my answer easily but I wanted to mention that :)

Comment: Thanks David, that did work but now I'm running into the other issues you anticipated! There's actually 83 rows I want it to loop through, and it can go upto hundreds from what I understand. If I set i to 82, it runs good and fast, but when I increase it to 100, it errors at the first variable of the in the loop. I spent most of the day looking at error handling, but I'm not solving the issue. I'm finding myself being self taught as well and reading alot of Walkenback stuff, any suggestions of good books to help along?

Comment: If I change the loop to `100` it doesn't error until `i = 84` (as expected) -- so it is the first statement inside the loop, but it doesn't error until the 84th attempt at evaluating that statement.  This might be super helpful for your debugging: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx  Also I made an update to the answer to possibly assist with the varying number of items, which should help you avoid that error.

Comment: The question now becomes more complicated, I trying to pull data from multiple links and have nested an if statement to limit the amount of data returned to a couple of weeks, but the code  prints 62 rows down and 152 rows in the second set. How can I get these to print after the header array and are there are any suggestions to reduce the coding as I think it's redundant. Thanks for the help.

Comment: well the first part of the follow-up is a new question and should be asked as a new question. the second part may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com